# toggleClass unexpected behavior on iphone

Tags: jquery, ios, css, iphone, toggleclass

I am using an ordered list to create clickable boxes for each hour of the day.  It works fine here at the desk, but I tried earlier tonight on my iphone and ran into a strange issue.

On my iphone... since the screen is narrower the boxes wrap onto new lines as they are floated left.  Well, I can only highlight/unhighlight the hours in the first line.  Any hours below that first line cannot be changed.  Now, if I turn my iphone to landscape (wider viewing area) then more boxes can be shown on the first line... same thing... everything in the first line can be changed on touch, but anything below that can't.  I can flip the phone from portrait to landscape back and forth... changing an hour in one and then not in the other depending if its on that first line or not.

Is there an issue with my css that would cause this?  I have tried all browsers here at my desk and they all work fine.  Only my iphone is causing this problem.

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hL2JC/

**html :**

```
<ol id="hour-select">
    <li>12am</li>
    <li>1am</li>
    <li>2am</li>
    <li>3am</li>
    <li>4am</li>
    <li>5am</li>
    <li>6am</li>
    <li>7am</li>
    <li>8am</li>
    <li>9am</li>
    <li>10am</li>
    <li>11am</li>
    <li>12pm</li>
</ol>
```

**css :**

```
#hour-select .hour-selected {
    background: #47a447;
    border:1px #398439 solid;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#hour-select {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#hour-select li {
    margin: 3px;
    padding:5px;
    float: left;
    width: 55px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px #cccccc solid;
    background:#e0e0e0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**js :**

```
$('#hour-select li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hour-selected');
});
```

Comment: I just tried the fiddle on my iphone out of curiosity and it works fine. On the site it doesn't. Guess I need to research this out more than I thought, but still open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I had to apply a clearfix to the ol element... everything works fine on the iphone now.